# "this Emacs binary lacks sound support"

Tags: audio, emacs

I'm trying to get Aquamacs Emacs to play a sound.

I have this:

```
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook 'my-org-after-todo)
(defun my-org-after-todo ()
(play-sound-file "~/Library/Sounds/InkSoundStroke3.aif"))
```

But I get this error:

```
This Emacs binary lacks sound support
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem in 2011 and fixed it with a little elisp package which I am now sharing in https://github.com/leoliu/play-sound-osx. Let me know if it works for you since I can't remember using it much :(

Comment: That recipe didn't work for me -- the `require` failed with `(file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "play-sound")`.  But I found a workaround: `(shell-command "afplay whatever.wav")`.